# zipfile добавляет в архив лишние папки

Tags: python, zip, zipfile

При архивировании изображения:

```
import zipfile

def archiver(path_to_file, path_to_new_zip, filename = 'new_file'):
    new_file = zipfile.ZipFile(f'{path_to_new_zip}\{filename}.zip', 'w')
    new_file.write(path_to_file, compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    new_file.close()
archiver(r'C:\Users\dimon\Desktop\zip archiver\files\aaa.jpg', r'C:\Users\dimon\Desktop\ziparchiver\zip', 'somefile')
```

вместо того чтобы просто заархивировать изображение, добавляются все папки на пути к изображению:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: [У метода write есть второй аргумент arcname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write), в котором вы можете указать любой желаемый путь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно передать в параметр `arcname` имя файла или путь, в коде ниже взял имя файла которое имеется у изначального файла `path_to_file.split("\")[-1]`, можно указать любое другое, например `new_image.jpg`

```py
import zipfile

def archiver(path_to_file, path_to_new_zip, filename = 'new_file'):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{path_to_new_zip}\{filename}.zip', 'w') as new_file:
        new_file.write(path_to_file, arcname=path_to_file.split("\")[-1], compress_type=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку из-за того что обратный слеш в конце строки в  path_to_file.split("\")[-1] , как можно это исправить?

Comment: @Dmitriy автор ответа забыл про экранирование спецсимволов в строковых литералах (и вы кстати в своём коде тоже забыли), замените во всех строках \ на \\

Comment: да, сорри, забыл,  я просто на ubuntu, у меня `/` и  экранирование не требовалось